# Changing Environment Inside Rake Enhance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I wanted to enhance an existing Rails 4 `db:test:prepare` task to call additional `db:seed` task to load some static reference data into my test database. I've written this custom task  in lib/tasks/test_seed.rake:

```
Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].enhance do
  Rails.env = "test"
  Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
end
```

However, the `rake db:test:prepare` task was still seeding development db, until I've explicitly established connection to "test". This is what worked:

```
Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].enhance do
  Rails.env = "test"
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('test')
  Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke
end
```

Though, it feels unnatural. Is there a better/proper way to enhance this `db:test:prepare` task that originally fires off against the development environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's as good as you're going to get. I ran into the same problem and that is the only way I got it working as well.

If you wanted to make it a little more elegant you could create a method like this:

```
def switch_environment(new_env, &block)
  original_env = Rails.env

  Rails.env = new_env.to_s
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection new_env.to_sym

  block.call
ensure
  Rails.env = original_env.to_s
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection original_env.to_sym
end
```

You could invoke it like this:

```
switch_environment :test do
  ...your code...
end
```

I tested this locally and it works as expected.